# Retrieving data from the hashMap in a multipartFormData

Tags: java, hashmap, multipartform-data

I'm having some trouble with my method, I can print the map if there's only 1 item in it but if I put more than 1, I get an out of bounds exception, do I have something implemented incorrectly?

```
public static Result update(){

        //get the body of the request
        RequestBody body = request().body();
        //Assign the type as MultipartFormData
        Http.MultipartFormData multippartBody = body.asMultipartFormData();
        // Pull the video from the MultipartFormData
        Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart videoFile = multippartBody.getFile("fileKey");
        // Pull the hashMap from the MultipartFormData
        Map<String, String[]> myMap  = multippartBody.asFormUrlEncoded();

        System.out.println(myMap.size());
        // Loop to print the contents of the hashMap
        for(int i =0; i < myMap.size(); i++){
            String param = "param" + (i + 1);
            System.out.println(myMap.get(param)[i]);    
        }

        }
```